# Getting a FileNotFoundError, despite directory existing

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

I'm trying to loop through files in a directory, but I keep getting a file not found error, despite the fact the directory is literally copy-pasted from Windows explorer. It's not stored in the C drive, so might that be the problem?

Here's the code.

```
# Setting directory
obj_path = "D:/ultivue/1604-2201 Core 8plex (All Runs) Region Object Data/run 2"

# For loop to go through all files in the path
for file in obj_path:
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
```

And here's the error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D'
```

Comment: What do you think `for file in obj_path:` does? Try `for file in obj_path: print(file)`. You probably mean to use `data = pd.read_csv(obj_path)`

Comment: `run 2` is the directory that the files are stored in, not the file itself.

Comment: `obj_path` is just a string. There is no way python could know that you want to use it as a path that needs to be listed. You have to use it with some file API that does that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are iterables in Python, which means they can be looped over. So something like `for char in 'word': print(char)` will print each character of `'word'` individually.

As written, you're trying to iterate over the string `obj_path` with `for _ in`, which is why it's stopping at 'D' (the first letter of the string) and throwing an error when it tries to open that as a csv.

You can use the `pathlib` module's `iterdir()` method to iterate over all the files in a given directory

```
import pathlib

# Setting directory (instantiate as a pathlib.Path object)
obj_path = pathlib.Path("D:/ultivue/1604-2201 Core 8plex (All Runs) Region Object Data/run 2")

# For loop to go through all files in the path
for file in obj_path.iterdir():
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    # do something with 'data' here, as it's going to be overwritten
    # on each loop iteration!
```

Comment: @fgootkind Glad I could help! If this answer worked for you, please mark it as "accepted" (click the check mark) so that others know this question has been answered. Happy coding!